# Execute parent controller method using modalInstance.result.then() AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-fullstack, angularjs-1.6

I'm trying run a class method (in the controller that creates my `$uibModal`) once the modal's "okay" button has been pressed. My understanding is that the `modalInstance` is returning a modal object from the component, and therein lies my problem... how can I interact with the parent controller instead of the component?

Example:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function () {
      // if close() called in component, do this in the parent controller
      this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);    
   }, function () {
      // if dissmised, do this
      console.log('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

This throws an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Here is a Plunker with the key items:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZY3Kr9g3MuT1AxsQKfsj?p=catalogue

AngularJS 1.6, using Angular Fullstack Generator 4.2.3

I've followed this documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to create a modal component and the modal works great. But I can't splice my array of users no matter what I try. Please help!

Comment: Your plunker is broken, but `TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined` usually points out  to incorrect `this` binding. Double check it.

Comment: I'm a little stuck with getting plunker to run (there are several parts of the app omitted; I was just using plunker (perhaps incorrectly) to show the component, controller, and modal html in my question.  What should I be double checking?  Oddly, if I call splice called outside of modalInstance.result.then(), it works flawlessly, but seems to get lost since the modalInstance returns an object.

Comment: check my answer below pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because of incorrectly bound `this` in your callback, try binding it explicitly to parent enclosing scope using `=>`:

```js
modalInstance.result.then(() => {
      // if close() called in component, do this in the parent controller
      this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);    
   }, function () {
      // if dissmised, do this
      console.log('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Comment: This worked!! I can't express my gratitude enough, thank you.

Comment: @rjkunde happy to help